# Purge [technical-writing]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I've came across the tag [technical-writing](/questions/tagged/technical-writing). It has no wiki explaining what it should be used for, and very many questions that are very off-topic here (some are perfect match for Workspace, some for ELL, some are more complicated cases).

I've voted to close some of them, I suggest reviewing those questions and deciding if that tag should be there, or it should be burninated.

Comment: Definitely worth looking into the 50 something questions with it applied, just take care not to remove it until those that need extra work receive it, or get into /review.

Comment: [Migrate to Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing)?

Comment: @TRiG: they're all too old to migrate.

Comment: Technical-writing questions are welcome on Writers.  The tag was gone by the time I saw this question so I can't easily look at them any more, but if there are any that seem good (but just off-topic on SO), please consider commenting to suggest the posters ask there.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: The tag isn't blacklisted, so you can (if you RSS) add the tag to your feeds and suggest when new ones come up.

Comment: @Won't, thanks!  I subscribe to some tags via that "subscribe" link on the individual tag, but until the tag shows up I can't do that.  Is there some way I can fake that up to get the email notifications I get for other tags?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=technical-writing&sort=newest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > > > > > > > [image]

Whipped.  Mark this puppy [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: What did you do? Go through all the questions, close those which are off topic (leaving helpful comments suggesting Writers SE where appropriate), and tidy the others, removing the tag while you were at it? That's what should have been done. What did you actually do?

Comment: @TRiG: I don't leave helpful comments.  Most of the questions were quite old, and 95% off topic.  So mostly I burned the tag and VTC.